Why do Hotmail/Outlook accounts work in Thunderbird on some PC's and not others?
Lately, I've found Thunderbird can log into a Hotmail or Outlook account on one PC, but using identical credentials and OAuth2 settings, it does not work on another PC.
In some cases, an account could be accessed on a dual-boot Windows-Linux PC when running Windows, but not under Linux.
Neither importing the profile nor recreating the account from scratch worked.
[This question might belong in Web Applications, but it also concerns the OS, so it's posted here -- please comment if you believe it inappropriate.]

Microsoft has added a third factor for email account authentication: the account name for the device, in addition to the email account name, user password, and additional passcode generated by Microsoft for OAuth2, shown below,

the email client must now forward the user name for the device. I.E., if logged in locally, the user name on a PC, or if logged into a domain, DOMAIN_NAME/user_name.
The latest version of Thunderbird (at least on Linux) now shows a dialog when creating a new Outlook or Hotmail account fails, providing a box to enter a user name that might differ from that on the PC, allowing the user to log into the account from a machine in a different domain, or where the user name differs.
After an initial login failure for a Hotmail or Outlook account, the dialog is shown, stating login might have failed due to the user name on the PC itself differing from that expected, and directions are shown for providing that information.
